# To enable Java version(for browser) using command line

Tags: java, command-line

Finding Java version in firefox (32-bit portable). I am using 64-bit machine which has multiple java version installed (both 32-bit and 64-bit). Want to find out the version of java used by firefox browser using **command line** or how can I enable the 32-bit version of java (for firefox browser) in java control panel using **command line?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't... you have to look it up in the firefox settings

Comment: Somebody still uses `Java` in the browser?

Comment: @sudo some people still use flash

Comment: Hope this will answer your question
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1002718

Comment: @PhilippSander Oh. I thought people stopped using flash because its not secure and etc. Looks like not all of them did.